# Any simple reason why spin 2 polarization tensor should be symmetric in $\mu\nu$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, gravity

Perhaps this is obvious to the not so tired one, but is there any reason why the five spin 2 polarization tensors $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{a}, a=1,\dots,5$ should be symmetric in $\mu\nu$?

While I'm at it, perhaps I should also ask where the tracelessness condition: 
$$g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{a}=0.$$

For more info, see Zee page 33.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full matrix representation is reducible and decomposes into three irreducible representations, given by the trace (spin 0), the antisymmetric part (spin 1), and the symmetric trace 0 part (spin 2).

Comment: Think I've seen this somewhere (Schutz maybe)... thanks.